# How do I get to a European university after Dutch MBO 3

Tags: university, quitting

First of all, I would like to explain my current education situation.
I have moved a lot when young, and have been part of different educational system, when 10, I was in the UK for 2 years, when 13, in Brazil for one year, and from 13-19, I was in The Netherlands, and from 19-22 (current), I was back in Brazil.

Computers have always been my main interest, I started programming at a young age (12 years old), and when 15, I had my first backend developer's job, however, I was never a good student, I got kicked out from a few schools, had some low grades and etc. In The Netherlands, the school systems works a bit differently (for the dutch readers: I was doing MBO), which is a like a "low technical school". I wanted to go to the university and start studying what I really wanted: Computer Science and Computer Security. So I finished my MBO 3 (you can only go to a university after 3 years of MBO 4), so clearly I was not allowed to enter the university. Fair enough.

When I arrive in Brazil, I decided to give a go, and translate my Dutch education papers, and voila, I was allowed to officially start a Bachelor of Computer Science, and so I did.

It's been 2 years now that I am studying a private university. However, I would like to return back to Europe, due a few personal reasons (I am completely alone here, and the way my current university works is not how I like it, mostly because they don't really care about anything, and so do the students. There is no organisation, and it seems I am not involving much, professors don't seem to be able to answer most of your questions and etc).

However, every university I tried to apply back in Europe, they ask me for my high school degree, and of course I "don't have any!" because of the MBO I did in The Netherlands. So I decided to get a transfer, again, all the universities I tried asked me for my High School grades. I tried one in which accepted a "university transfer", so I sent them my university papers, and my MBO paper (hoping they would accept me), well, no, they sent me a letter saying "due to the school you did in The Netherlands, we are not allowed to accept you".

This is starting to make me very upset, so I am trying to make a decision weather I should drop out of university, return back to Europe and start doing some certification on the area I mostly like. Though I am not sure if this is a good idea. It saddens me because I really like to be part of a university (not the current though). Currently, my aim would be to follow as a independent security researcher.

How worth is dropping out of university? What should I be aware and what are the main steps I should follow to be a security researcher on my own?

**Update**
If relevant, I have the following citizenship: German and Dutch.

Comment: You might want to rephrase the title question. 'Should I drop the university' is something only you can answer. 'How do I get to a European university after Dutch MBO 3', if I read your question correctly, is a question this stack can advise you on.

Comment: This question appears to be very specialized to your very unusual situation, and it also doesn't appear generalizable to graduate studies. I'm not sure if the question is a good fit for this site.

Comment: Unfortunately, as Drecate indicates, this question is both far too specialized to be of general help to other site users, and directed at undergraduate admissions, which are also off-topic here.

Comment: Dutch HBOs accept people with an MBO 4 degree. After passing the first year (propedeuse) you can make the switch to a Dutch university. At this point your high school does not matter anymore. See if you can somehow get MBO 4. Netherlands also offers a test as an application to many programs if you're over 21. Just google "21+ test". Just some ideas :)

Comment: I bet that the Bazil Uni is much easier than the Dutch one .Why not finish the Brazil Stuff then return to Netherlands.I guess you have EU passport .If you have your Brazil degree your chances are much better.